# SQL WKT draws well with geometry, but not with geography data type

Tags: sql-server, well-known-text, sql-server-spatial, geography-data-type

I have a following piece of code

```
DECLARE @g geometry;
DECLARE @borders geography;   
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('SOME WKT', 0); 
SET @borders = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(@g.MakeValid().STAsText(),4326)
SELECT @g;
SELECT @borders;
```

Since it's too long to paste it here, WKT Can be fond at this link: https://justpaste.it/6qw0a

Can someone please explain to me, why it displays well when I draw it as geometry, but when I try to draw it as a geography, it displays entire world instead of a small group of islands.

Here's the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Interesting... there is an STMpolyfrom text (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stmpolyfromtext-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) but I couldn't get it to work...

Comment: Wrong winding order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @geom GEOMETRY = 'POLYGON ((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0))';
DECLARE @geog GEOGRAPHY = @geom.MakeValid().STUnion(@geom.STStartPoint()).STAsText()
```

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/66678/125538) topic had the answer to my question